# Magento loading base theme instead of downloaded theme

Tags: magento, themes, e-commerce

Im trying to install a theme on magento 1.9. Have copied all files into the correct places.

Under System -> Configuration -> Design -> Themes I have set templates, skin, layout and default all to the theme name.

The problem I think i am having is 'Current package name' It was originally set to 'rwd' and when it is set to this it loads the default 1.9 magento theme. However when i change this to 'default' it loads the magento base theme. If i set the package name to the name of the theme it also loads the base package.

Skin Directory Structure

[image: Skin Directory Structure]

Design Directory Structure

[image]

Comment: your downloaded theme is under frontend/default/yourtheme or frontend/yourtheme ?

Comment: Its under frontend/default/yourtheme. I have just tried frontend/yourtheme and it defaulted to the base theme again.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Did you check your custom design? Access: System > Design

[image]

Comment: Loaded System -> Design and its blank as the above screenshot indicates. Should I add anything into here?

Comment: There are some places you need to check: 1. Check custom design for category; 2. Check custom design for specific product; 3. Check custom design for specific CMS page

Comment: Thanks for your response. I have checked it for all of the above. E.g. CMS -> Pages -> Homepage -> Design. All fields in the custom design form are empty or say 'Please select' This is the same for all categorys, products I have checked. Any other suggestions?

Comment: Could you post directory structure of your skin and design directory?

Comment: Sure, have just updated the question with images. I await your reply

Comment: Hi, I have just moved the theme folder into the default folder under the design structure. This has resolved my issue, thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

just cross check following configuration with your configuration.

[image]

Then clear cache and check.

Comment: I have just changed the settings to this. It is still defaulting to the base theme. The current file structure is frontend/default/yourtheme/default/css etc. Does that seem right?

Comment: I have just change the file structure to be frontend/default/yourtheme/cssimagesetc. Still loading the base theme.

Comment: your folders should be like this frontend/default/yourtheme/layout,frontend/default/yourtheme/template , skin/frontend/default/yourtheme/css

Comment: check what is cssimagesetc.what is their in cssimagesetc

Comment: Sorry, my folder structure is frontend/default/yourtheme/css. frontend/default/yourtheme/images etc. It's still loading the base theme. Any other suggestions?

Comment: Hi, I have just moved the theme folder into the default folder under the design structure. This has resolved my issue, thanks for the help

Comment: hi pradeep, I create packege name "test" and inside that create themefolder "theme" in app and skin but while i print current theme and current package.it return 'rwd'.and "theme"..so I cant able to set "rwd" to "test"